# Cribbage scoring for a run of 4 out of sequence

Tags: cribbage

The play was the following set of cards: 4, 3, 6, 4, 5. Should the score be for 4 points for the 3,6, 4, 5 or only 6, 4, 5?

Comment: Isn't 6, 4, 5 just as out-of-sequence as 3, 6, 4, 5?

Answer (score 6):

Sequence does not matter.  4 points for 3-6-4-5.

Comment: Double run of 4 cards always scores 10

Comment: During the play?  I believe you are mistaken.

Comment: Doh!  I didn't read that part...